# Regex for extracting substring from html string in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I get html source code as a string, like below. And I need to get the substring `ZAgAAAAAAAGE9MTAwNjE4OT` which is between `abcid.wust=` and `&abcid.action=`
How to do it? Thanks!

```
    html is <html><head> 

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>preCallBack.jsp</title>
    ...
    var gateway = 'https://test.abc.com/check2.html?abcid.wust=ZAgAAAAAAAGE9MTAwNjE4OT&abcid.action=uilogin&&registType=null';
...
```

Comment: try parsing the html string using a library instead of using a regex, anyway if you still want to do via regex, try using a combination of positive lookbehind with positive lookahead, see [`this link`](https://regex101.com/r/bDUl2E/1) I made.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Thank you very much! It works. How to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, Your comments works for this issue please post it below as an answer for this case.